# xPDO And Class 'PDO' not found

Tags: php

i'm trying to use the [xPDO](http://xpdo.org/) because not all old version of the php has the PDO class

and some one told me the xpdo class will work if there is no pdo in the host and now i'm trying to use it and it tell me

```
Fatal error: Class 'PDO' not found
```

Comment: what? give me one reason to use it instead the pdo if i have it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the version 1.x of xPDO ([link](http://rtfm.modx.com/display/XPDO10/PDO+Emulation)) that supports PDO emulation (2.x doesn't).

Answer (score 2):

It is not a substitute of PDO but a DB layer which is Built on PDO. It won't work if there is no PDO.

> Built on PDO, the standard DB layer for PHP 5.1+

Comment: give me one reason to use it instead the pdo if i have it

Comment: @MacOs It is doing something which is usually called ORM. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping

Answer (score 1):

xPDO does not replace PDO, it extends it. You still need PDO to be on the server.

Frankly, if you need PDO and your host doesn't have it, you don't search for alternatives, you search for another host.